# react-native fetch returns odd response

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I'm using fetch to get some stuff from an API like this:

```
fetch('http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
        .then(
            data => console.log(data),
            error => console.log(error)
        )
```

But what I get back is the following object, not the actual data

```
_bodyBlob: Blob
_bodyInit: Blob
headers: Headers
ok: true
status: 200
statusText: undefined
type: "default"
url: "http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json"
```

Can someone explain me whats wrong?
I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7):

To get the data from the response you have to call `data.json();` Example:

```
fetch('http://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

(Assuming the response is in json).

Comment: this is not working. I am almost dying to see the body response from post request. it works in postman but not in react native app

Comment: I get "Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'."

Comment: Smells like there is another version of `fetch` used by RN.  There _is_ no `json` or `text` method on this response (or its prototype chain).  This may be related to a bridge from native we're using.  Other calls from RN have `json` and `text` as expected.